# How can I build an absolute URL from a relative on in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, href, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm tryhing to figure out a way to get an absoulte URL given a value I've scrubbed from an anchor tag's href attribute.  I came up with

```
url = a.attr("href")
if url !~ /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix
  url = "http://#{url}"
end
```

thinking that if the href is only "www.mydomain.com," I could cretea proper URL by appending "http://".  However the above logic fails if the URl is relative (e.g. "/abc/def").  Is there a foolproof way I can build an absolute URL from an anchor tag's HREF attributre that may or may not be an absoulte URL itself?  Note that I do have access to the original URL that contains the page with the anchor tag.

**Edit:**  But you're saying, hey, you sorry SOB, that's not how a browser treats an href.  If it sees "www.whatever.com," it treats it as a relative path!  So your question is bogus!  Well cupcake, even though you're right, that's not my question.  I want to recognize a domain and turn it into a valid URL AND recognize a path beginning with "/" and turn that into a valid URL.  Impossible you say?  Make that youre answer and watch your points go up as others agree with you.

Comment: href "www.mydomain.com" is an invalid URI. Even more so with a comma at the end.

Comment: here's super-simple logic: if it starts with a forward slash, then it must be a relative URI, prepend scheme and host. Otherwise prepend only scheme, if it does not already contain one.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So `//example.com/foo` is a “relative URI” and should have the scheme and host prepended? ;)

Comment: @coreyward: I didn't say it's foolproof logic. :) Garbage in - garbage out.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's not garbage though — it's a protocol relative URL; on a webpage it instructs the browser to use the existing scheme.

Comment: @coreyward: ah, my bad! You are right, of course. So complicated, this stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using URI.join, which is part of the [built-in URI library](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html).

One major benefit, especially if you're parsing href attributes from a web page, is that it can resolve any relative URL given the page's absolute URL.

```
require 'uri'

base = 'http://example.com/subsection/'

URI.join(base, 'inner.html')        #=> http://example.com/subsection/inner.html
URI.join(base, '/index.html')       #=> http://example.com/index.html
URI.join(base, 'http://google.com') #=> http://google.com
```

EDIT: Making an exception for hrefs that start like 'www.example.com' adds another wrinkle. Treating it as a domain is nonstandard. Given that disclaimer, Here's a quick and dirty regex that might help:

```
href = 'www.example.com'
href.gsub!(/^((([a-z0-9\-]*)\.)+(com|net|org|edu))\/?/i, 'http://\1/') #=> http://www.example.com/
URI.join(base, href) #=> http://www.example.com/
```

Keep in mind that no standard URI parser will make the same exception. Every major browser will treat 'www.example.com' as a path instead of a domain name. If you're getting those hrefs from live web pages, the links are already broken.

Comment: If I start with just an "href", is your suggestion to check if it begins wi th "www", apply your "dirty" logic and then try URL.join?  This probably won't work, right, because what if the domain is "www2.mydoeina.com" or "subdomain.mydomein.com"?

Comment: I edited the regexp so it works with com, net, org, and edu. It works the way you want with www2.mydoeina.com and subdomain.mydomein.com. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to catch every possible exception. If it ends with .cab, for example, it might be a domain name or a link to a compressed file. An exception for only the most common top-level domains might work in this case.

Comment: Best answer; elegant use of URI. 

An href of "www.example.com" will not actually resolve to that domain in a browser; it's a broken link. I'd say that makes it not a case to be worried about.

Comment: @JimMeyer Agreed. I've been trying to explain this to Dave for the last 4 hours without luck.

Comment: Guys, www.example.com may not be valid, that's fine.  That's not my question.  My question is how do I take "www.example.com", extracted from an href and make a valid URL, "http://www.example.com".  @dtroof, what condition am I checking before I run your line with "href.gsub"?

Comment: You don't need to check a condition. If the href doesn't start with a string that looks like a domain name, it gets left as it is.

Comment: Uri join is buggy for ftp. Try `URI.join("ftp://ftp.com/fit/", "file")` `undefined method 'typecode' for "file":String`. So use addressable instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've done similar things before using [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable). Here's an example:

```
current_page = Addressable::URI.parse('http://www.example.org/example/?bar=baz')
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('foo')

# if uri is only a non-relative path, you need to prepend 
# the path from the location of the document
if uri.path && ! uri.path.start_with?('/')
  uri.path = File.join current_page.path, uri.path
end

uri.scheme = current_page.scheme if uri.scheme.nil?
uri.host = current_page.host if uri.host.nil?
uri.to_s #=> "http://www.example.org/example/foo"
```

If you want to clean up your URLs, you might also want to check into using [PostRank::URI](https://github.com/postrank-labs/postrank-uri).

Note: `www.example.org` on its own in an `href` is actually a *path* not a *host*.

Comment: Hi, THanks but this isn't working.  If you replace "foo" with "www.mydemain.com", the result at the end of your block is "http://www.example.org/example/www.mydomain.com", but I woudl expect it to be "http://www.mydemain.com."

Comment: @Dave I explained in my note that `www.example.org` is not a host when it appears by itself in an `href` attribute. It's treated as a path. Try it. Put it on a webpage and click on it and you'll go to `{current_path}/www.example.org`.

Comment: @Dave If you specify `//www.example.org` or `http://www.example.org` it works as you expect. Also: please [stop using “mydomain” as an example site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke).

Comment: HI, I realize "www.example.org" may not be valid, but that is what I'm pulling occassionally and that is what I want to get to work as I described.  I wish I could tell these people to write their pages differently, but I'm forced to deal with what I have.

Comment: @Dave Can you share an example? Do those links go where you expect or are they broken?

Comment: The example would be the href contains the value "www.example.org".  (except its not example.org, of course).  Yes the links do go to the right place.

Comment: @Dave — Can you please link me to that example? This isn't how browsers work. The page would either need to be overriding the default behavior with JS and using a location redirect or using a (relatively rare) `base` tag for that to work.

Comment: Think of it like this, if I type in "www.example.com" in my browser, it automatically prepends "http://" making the link "http://www.example.com".  I want to mimic that behavior if I extract such a domain from an href.

Comment: @Dave I understand what you're saying, but the fact is that's not what you're going to encounter on websites because that's not the way browsers treat `href` attribute values. If it doesn't have a protocol/scheme it's a relative link. If it doesn't have a leading forward slash it's relative to the folder. If it does have a leading forward slash it's relative to the root. If it has two leading forward slashes it's relative to the protocol/scheme.

Comment: Thanks but that's not my quesiton.  My quesiton doesn't say I want to mimic how a browser treats an href, my question wants to turn a domain into a valid URL.  If that's impossible then that's too bad for me!  I suspect, though, with all my limited intelligence, that this is not impossible.

Comment: @Dave “given a value I've scrubbed from an anchor tag's href attribute”